# Smpp receive sms in php

Tags: php, smpp

how to run the following code continually when a persistent connection is established to the SMSC. and what is the clear meaning of setRecvTimeout(60000) in here.

```
   <?php   //Receive sms

require_once 'smppclient.class.php';
require_once 'sockettransport.class.php';

// Construct transport and client
$transport = new SocketTransport(array('smpp.provider.com'),3600);
$transport->setRecvTimeout(60000); // for this example wait up to 60 seconds for data

for(;;){
$smpp = new SmppClient($transport);

// Activate binary hex-output of server interaction
$smpp->debug = true;
$transport->debug = true;

// Open the connection
$transport->open();
$smpp->bindReceiver("USERNAME","PASSWORD");

// Read SMS and output
$sms = $smpp->readSMS();

$read = $sms -> message;// reads the message
echo $read."\n";

$phone = $sms -> source-> value; //gets the phone number
echo $phone."\n"; 

echo "SMS:\n";
//var_dump($sms);

// Close connection
$smpp->close();

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That simply means to set the internal timeout to 60 seconds.  So if it doesn't receive anything after 60 seconds, it means that the connection is disconnected.

That's the general principle of a timeout.

Comment: if anyone could please tell me what are the ways to run this code continuously?

Comment: will setting a timeout be an issue to run this code continuously?

Comment: That should be irrelevant.  Did you try it already?  If not, go ahead!